# Looking for a specific novel/series about (supernaturally) "Gifted" children (possibly children "of the Sun"?) with an older sister, twins and a baby?

Tags: story-identification

One of them could fly I think? The details are pretty fuzzy but I probably read it some time between 2007 and 2012?

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=of+the+sun&type=Fiction+Titles?

Comment: Was it all of those people at once? Or books focused on one generation of the family or another?

Comment: gifted child, older sister, twins reminds me of Wrinkle in Time universe

Comment: Was the story set in our world, or was it a fantastic world? I may have an answer that fits almost all the points, but it is set in a really different world

Comment: @Lyzvaleska it may have been a fantasy world? I remember that it definitely didn't take place in the American continent...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds a bit like [Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&ved=2ahUKEwjBlJHr2YHoAhWny4UKHQ2vAXIQFjAMegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodreads.com%2Fbook%2Fshow%2F9460487-miss-peregrine-s-home-for-peculiar-children&usg=AOvVaw2ymXA2j48zHkjKHs0C6a3U). 
The book was released in 2011 and one of the characters is a girl who floats away if she doesn‘t wear iron shoes. There is a pair of twins and they have pale gray, scaly skin with gray serpentine eyes and fangs but wear a sack over their head. All the other children have a „gift“ too.
There are some other characters without powers and there are some villains.

I have to say that I never read the book but I heard of the film and know the story a bit. If you want to read the correct storyline I would recommed to read the description in goodreads.

Comment: Sadly I've seen the move and that's not it.

Comment: It was worth a try. I hope you find the right book.